# JQuery slider change event not firing in ROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple JQuery slider on a Rails ERB page.  I'm trying to get an alert to fire on change but it just isn't happening.

For what it is worth, the slider does work.

I've placed this code in home.html.erb.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
  h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  body, p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  }
  </style>

  <!-- Load jQuery and jQuery UI -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <!-- Load the jQuery UI CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />


  <!-- jQuery UI Slider code -->
  <script>

  // When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Create a new jQuery UI Slider element
    // and set some default parameters.
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 50,
      min: 20,
      max: 300,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {

        // While sliding, update the value in the #amount div element
        $( "#amount" ).html( ui.value );

      },
      change: function (event, data) {
        alert(data.value)
    }

    });


    // Set the initial slider amount in the #amount div element
    var value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
    $( "#amount" ).html( value );

  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <!--  The div that is used as the slider container  -->
  <div id="slider" style="margin-top:100px;"></div>

  <br /><br /><br />

  <!--  The div that is used to display the slider value  -->
  <div id="amount" style="color:#777;font-size:72px;text-align:center;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2kWN3/

Comment: Odd. It works for me on my home machine.  Perhaps it is an issue with Chrome under Ubuntu.